# Control WPF progress bar from WinForms app

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, wpf-controls, interop

I have an WinForms app built with vb .net to which I've added a WPF user control. The WPF user control consists of only a progressbar. I can drag the WPF control from the toolbax and add it to the Main Form in WinForms vb .net. But I don't know how to let my WinForms app dynamically set the value for the WPF progress bar. Anyway I can dynamically set the WPF control progress bar's value from my WinForms app?

Note: The reason Im using WPF progress bar instead of using WinForms progress bar is so that I can have blue colored progress bar in my WinForms app.

Comment: You can have a blue ProgressBar using the WinForms standard control. You just need to paint it with the color you like.

Comment: @Jimi The progress liquid must be blue in color instead of green.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just said, you can paint it. Make a Custom Control derived from ProgressBar, add these styles to the Consttructor: `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);`, override `OnPaint` and paint the color you like (actually, two colors: the main color and the upper shadow, which should be the lower color + an alpha value, e.g., `Color highColor = Color.FromArgb(160, baseColor);`). The size of the *shadow* can be fixed or dynamic (based on the height of the ProgressBar).

Comment: You can render the ProgressBar frame overriding OnPaintBackground and using `ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle);` (plus some custom adjustments). You might say: *all that for a ProgrssBar*. Of course, but if you add a WPF control, your app becomes DpiAware when maybe it's not, so you'll have to recalibrate all the UI...

Comment: @Jimi ok I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it may not be as straightforward as it may look like on paper, here's a custom ProgressBar that allows to set the Color of the bar and also change its style *on the fly*.

The **`ProgressBarStyle`** property sets the current style: the **`BarStyle.Standard`** style uses the [ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer.drawhorizontalbar) method to draw its background, while the **`BarStyle.Flat`** selects the `Parent.BackColor` as background color and uses a fixed white border to draw the ProgressBar bounds and [SystemColors.Highlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemcolors) as the bar color. Of course it can be changed to support any other color and the Standard style.

The [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat) class is used to center the text of the ProgressBar (in `Standard` style only. This can also be easily changed), setting both Horizontal and Vertical alignment to `StringAlignment.Center`.
The text color changes automatically to adapt to the Brightness of the ProgressBar color (it's just a simple adjustment, the `HSL` value on its own cannot always determine what text color better fits a background color).

<sub>Some *magic values* are just offsets used to adapt the drawing rectangles to the shapes designed by `ProgressBarRenderer`</sub>

---

**This is how it works**:

[image: ProgressBar Custom]

**VB.Net version of the Custom Control:**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class ProgressBarCustomColor
    Inherits ProgressBar

    Private m_ParentBackColor As Color = SystemColors.Window
    Private m_ProgressBarStyle As BarStyle = BarStyle.Standard
    Private m_FlatBorderColor As Color = Color.White

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint Or
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
    End Sub

    Public Enum BarStyle
        Standard
        Flat
    End Enum

    Public Property ProgressBarStyle As BarStyle
        Get
            Return m_ProgressBarStyle
        End Get
        Set
            m_ProgressBarStyle = Value
            If DesignMode Then Me.Parent?.Refresh()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property FlatBorderColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_FlatBorderColor
        End Get
        Set
            m_FlatBorderColor = Value
            If DesignMode Then Me.Parent?.Refresh()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnParentChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnParentChanged(e)
        m_ParentBackColor = If(Me.Parent IsNot Nothing, Me.Parent.BackColor, SystemColors.Window)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
        Dim rect = Me.ClientRectangle

        If m_ProgressBarStyle = BarStyle.Standard Then
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, rect)

            Dim baseColor = Color.FromArgb(240, Me.BackColor)
            Dim highColor = Color.FromArgb(160, baseColor)
            Using baseBrush = New SolidBrush(baseColor),
                  highBrush = New SolidBrush(highColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highBrush, 1, 2, rect.Width, 9)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 1, 7, rect.Width, rect.Height - 1)
            End Using
        Else
            Using pen = New Pen(m_FlatBorderColor, 2),
                  baseBrush = New SolidBrush(m_ParentBackColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 0, 0, rect.Width - 1, rect.Height - 1)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 1, 1, Me.ClientSize.Width - 2, Me.ClientSize.Height - 2)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim rect = New RectangleF(PointF.Empty, Me.ClientSize)
        rect.Width = CType(rect.Width * (CType(Me.Value, Single) / Me.Maximum), Integer)
        rect.Size = New SizeF(rect.Width - 2, rect.Height)

        Dim hsl As Single = Me.ForeColor.GetBrightness()
        If m_ProgressBarStyle = BarStyle.Standard Then DrawStandardBar(e.Graphics, rect, hsl)
        If m_ProgressBarStyle = BarStyle.Flat Then DrawFlatBar(e.Graphics, rect, hsl)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DrawStandardBar(g As Graphics, rect As RectangleF, hsl As Single)
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality

        Dim baseColor = Color.FromArgb(240, Me.ForeColor)
        Dim highColor = Color.FromArgb(160, baseColor)

        Using baseBrush = New SolidBrush(baseColor),
              highBrush = New SolidBrush(highColor),
              sf = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces)
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

            g.FillRectangle(highBrush, 1, 2, rect.Width, 9)
            g.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 1, 7, rect.Width, rect.Height - 1)
            g.DrawString($"{Me.Value} %", Me.Parent.Font,
                If(hsl > 0.49F, Brushes.Black, Brushes.White), Me.ClientRectangle, sf)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub DrawFlatBar(g As Graphics, rect As RectangleF, hsl As Single)
        Using baseBrush = New SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight)
            g.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 2, 2, rect.Width - 2, rect.Height - 4)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

**C# version:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class ProgressBarCustomColor : ProgressBar
{
    private Color m_ParentBackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    private Color m_FlatBorderColor = Color.White;
    private BarStyle m_ProgressBarStyle = BarStyle.Standard;
    public ProgressBarCustomColor()
    {
        this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
            ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    public enum BarStyle { Standard, Flat }

    public BarStyle ProgressBarStyle {
        get => m_ProgressBarStyle;
        set {
            m_ProgressBarStyle = value;
            if (DesignMode) this.Parent?.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public Color FlatBorderColor {
        get => m_FlatBorderColor;
        set {
            m_FlatBorderColor = value;
            if (DesignMode) this.Parent?.Refresh();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        m_ParentBackColor = this.Parent?.BackColor ?? SystemColors.Window;
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        var rect = this.ClientRectangle;

        if (m_ProgressBarStyle == BarStyle.Standard) {
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, rect);

            var baseColor = Color.FromArgb(240, this.BackColor);
            var highColor = Color.FromArgb(160, baseColor);
            using (var baseBrush = new SolidBrush(baseColor))
            using (var highBrush = new SolidBrush(highColor)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highBrush, 1, 2, rect.Width, 9);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 1, 7, rect.Width, rect.Height - 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            using (var pen = new Pen(m_FlatBorderColor, 2))
            using (var baseBrush = new SolidBrush(m_ParentBackColor)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 0, 0, rect.Width - 1, rect.Height - 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 1, 1, this.ClientSize.Width - 2, this.ClientSize.Height - 2);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var rect = new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, this.ClientSize);
        rect.Width = (int)(rect.Width * ((float)this.Value / this.Maximum));
        rect.Size = new SizeF(rect.Width - 2, rect.Height);

        float hsl = this.ForeColor.GetBrightness();
        if (m_ProgressBarStyle == BarStyle.Standard) DrawStandardBar(e.Graphics, rect, hsl);
        if (m_ProgressBarStyle == BarStyle.Flat) DrawFlatBar(e.Graphics, rect, hsl);
    }

    private void DrawStandardBar(Graphics g, RectangleF rect, float hsl)
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        var baseColor = Color.FromArgb(240, this.ForeColor);
        var highColor = Color.FromArgb(160, baseColor);

        using (var baseBrush = new SolidBrush(baseColor))
        using (var highBrush = new SolidBrush(highColor))
        using (var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces)) {
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            g.FillRectangle(highBrush, 1, 2, rect.Width, 9);
            g.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 1, 7, rect.Width, rect.Height - 1);
            g.DrawString($"{this.Value} %", this.Parent.Font, 
                hsl > .49f ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.White, this.ClientRectangle, sf);
        }
    }

    private void DrawFlatBar(Graphics g, RectangleF rect, float hsl)
    {
        using (var baseBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight)) {
            g.FillRectangle(baseBrush, 2, 2, rect.Width - 2, rect.Height - 4);
        }
    }
}
```