# Why wouldn't this label show up despite its Visible parameter being set to True and its Text parameter containing a string?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

As can be seen in the image above, I have four labels that are on top of some PictureBoxes. Note that I added the blue text and arrow in the image in Paint; they are not elements of the form.

By default, these labels have their Visible parameters set to False and their Text parameters are set to being empty. At specific points in the program, one of the labels is selected to both have Visible set to True and to have a 3-digit-or-less number alongside a percent sign(in the format ### % in which # is a digit) in black size 12.75 Microsoft Sans Serif font.
However, only the top label(the one being pointed at by the blue arrow) actually becomes visible and displays its text when its parameters are changed in this way. The top image below shows what the top label looks like when this happens, while the bottom image below shows what the other three labels look like when the same process is applied to any of them.

[image]

[image]

Ignoring the difference in aspect ratio between the two images, the only important difference between the two is that in the first one, the label is visible and is displaying "75 %", while in the second one, the label is not visible so there is no number or percent sign.

I know for a fact that in the second instance the label's Visible property is set to True and its text is set to "75 %" through debugging, but none of this shows up when the form is running. Another thing that I have determined through debugging is that this issue is either caused by or at least apparent in the function below, since this function is the only code block that:

a) is used in every instance in which the labels are set to having Visible be True and their text being set to that "### %" format, and also

b) distinguishes between the different labels.

```
private void UpdateHpText(PictureBox HPBox) //the function in question
        {
            //this conditional tree takes "HPBox," one of the Pictureboxes that the labels overlap(the green bars), and uses it to decide which label needs to be altered
            if(HPBox == side2HPbox1) 
            {
                //Side2HPText1 is the top label, Side2HPText2 is the next from the top label, and etc.
                Side2HPText1.Visible = HPBox.Visible; //I know from debugging that HpBox.Visible should be set to True in the instance I am having trouble with
                side2HPbox1DisplayNum = (BasicProcess.side2[0].HP.value * 100) / (BasicProcess.side2[0].HP.max); //calculates the number displayed in the Label's text
                Side2HPText1.Text = side2HPbox1DisplayNum + " %"; //sets the label's text
                //in the above instance, the label should have Visible set to True, and its Text should be assigned to a string. However, I'm not having issues with this block.
            }
            //so tell me, is there ANY difference between the above block and the below block other than:(see differences in documentation of each line)
            else if (HPBox == side2HPbox2)
            {
                Side2HPText2.Visible = HPBox.Visible; //a different label is targeted here
                side2HPbox2DisplayNum = (BasicProcess.side2[1].HP.value * 100) / (BasicProcess.side2[1].HP.max); //BasicProcess.side2[1] is being used instead here because it targets the object that is assigned to the label in this block, and side2HPBoxDisplayNum is just used in the final line of this block for the displayed string
                Side2HPText2.Text = side2HPbox2DisplayNum + " %";
            //from what I see, both blocks are functionally the same, and I also know that to be the case from debugging, but when the form runs, I get a completely different result for each block.
            }
            else if (HPBox == side2HPbox3)
            {
                Side2HPText3.Visible = HPBox.Visible;
                side2HPbox3DisplayNum = (BasicProcess.side2[2].HP.value * 100) / BasicProcess.side2[2].HP.max;
                Side2HPText3.Text = side2HPbox3DisplayNum + " %";
            }
            else
            {
                Side2HPText4.Visible = HPBox.Visible;
                side2HPbox4DisplayNum = (BasicProcess.side2[3].HP.value * 100) / BasicProcess.side2[3].HP.max;
                Side2HPText4.Text = side2HPbox4DisplayNum + " %";
            }
        }
```

As you can read in the code above, there shouldn't be any difference between what the top label looks like when its block runs and what the second label looks like when its block runs, but there is. This makes me think that I might be having a GUI error that I'm not noticing in my code. One thing I've learned about GUI in Winforms is that that threading can have an impact on how the GUI updates itself. For that reason, I will post the relevant code in my program below that uses Async and Await, which might have an impact on threading.

```
                                    Side2HPBoxList[BasicProcess.side2.IndexOf(targetList[0])].Visible = true; //sets one of the green bar PictureBox's Visible parameter to True
                                    await Task.Delay(500); //waits half a second
                                    targetList[0] = char1ChosenSkill.effect(targetList[0]); //this can be ignored since it does not effect the PictureBox or Label
                                    Side2HPBoxList[BasicProcess.side2.IndexOf(targetList[0])].Image = UpdateHpBar(targetList[0], BasicProcess.side2); //runs UpdateHPBar
                                    UpdateHpText(Side2HPBoxList[BasicProcess.side2.IndexOf(targetList[0])]);
                                    await Task.Delay(1500); //waits 1.5 seconds
                                    Side2HPBoxList[BasicProcess.side2.IndexOf(targetList[0])].Visible = false; //sets one of the green bar PictureBox's Visible back to false
                                    Menu2Background.Visible = (char2 != null); //this can be ignored since it does not effect the PictureBox or Label
```

However, I don't think that Task.Delay could genuinely scuff up the GUI that much, especially considering that it runs for each and every label the same way.

Another potential reason for my program not running correctly is the properties of the labels. For that reason, I will post them below. Please don't forget that even though the Text and Visible elements are set to being empty and False respectively here, they should be set to containing a string and being True at the point in the program that I am having trouble with.

```
            // 
            // Side2HPText1
            // 
            this.Side2HPText1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Side2HPText1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(2)))), ((int)(((byte)(218)))), ((int)(((byte)(55)))));
            this.Side2HPText1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Side2HPText1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1109, 127);
            this.Side2HPText1.Name = "Side2HPText1";
            this.Side2HPText1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 26);
            this.Side2HPText1.TabIndex = 66;
            this.Side2HPText1.Visible = false;
```

```
            // 
            // Side2HPText2
            // 
            this.Side2HPText2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Side2HPText2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(2)))), ((int)(((byte)(218)))), ((int)(((byte)(55)))));
            this.Side2HPText2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Side2HPText2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1109, 279);
            this.Side2HPText2.Name = "Side2HPText2";
            this.Side2HPText2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 26);
            this.Side2HPText2.TabIndex = 70;
            this.Side2HPText2.Visible = false;
```

I haven't noticed any differences here that could be relevant to my issue, but maybe someone will.

Anyhow, if I haven't provided enough relevant information here, feel free to ask me to provide more.

EDIT:
I'm not entirely sure how to provide a reproducible example without sharing absolutely all of my code. I will start documenting a big chunk of it and tack it to the bottom of this post by the end of today, but it will take time. Hopefully doing that will help

EDIT 2:
Actually, I can provide some more info before I do that. Firstly, when I said that I determined that the Visible parameter was set to True and the Text was set to a string by debugging, I meant that I set up a breakpoint and looked in the Autos field in Debug mode to determine that this was the case.
I also have brought the Labels to the front several times now(thinking that maybe I did it wrong before or something), so I am confident that they are brought to the front. I also put a line of code in UpdateHPText saying:

```
Side2HPText2.Parent = Side2HPText2.Parent;
```

so I could see that value in the Autos field. It turns out that this value was set to the form it's on(BattleTemplate4), so I think that that is fine.

EDIT 3:
Here's a pastebin link to the `InitializeComponent` function since it won't fit the character limit: https://pastebin.com/WRRJ5n4d (a commenter asked for it)

EDIT 4:
Okay, I think I've determined that it's a painting issue. I'm going to switch over to having the text either drawn on since I don't think it's worth the trouble to resolve an issue that can be mollified by trying something else that's equally functional.

EDIT 5:
NEVERMIND! I didn't expand to the two comments that weren't visible, and used the `.BringToFront()` function on the text in `UpdateHPText,` and it worked. Thanks @Idle_Mind for resolving my issue.

Comment: It's not clear how *threading* is handled here (you're mentioning it but forgot to post that code). Anyway, have you tried to simply `BringToFront()` those Labels? As a side note, it's probably better to draw that text directly onto each PictureBox's surface (much less *moving parts* to handle). Even better if the PictureBox is a Custom Control.

Comment: There are all kinds of reasons the label might not get shown. But since you failed to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say for sure why it doesn't in your case. Please fix your question.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `Side2HPText2.Visible = HPBox.Visible;`. Confirm the breakpoint is hit. Confirm `HPBox.Visible == true;` Also, check `Side2HPText2.Parent` has a `non-null` value.

Comment: _"I'm not entirely sure how to provide a reproducible example without sharing absolutely all of my code"_ -- well, good time for you to learn a new skill! The basic approach: copy your code into a new project; remove parts of the code a bit at a time, starting with the most-obviously irrelevant parts. If you remove something and the problem goes away, you're close to being able to answer your question yourself. Keep removing things until nothing else can be removed without the problem disappearing. Post _that_. See also [ask], especially the articles linked at the bottom. And of course [mcve].

Comment: "I also have brought the Labels to the front several times now(thinking that maybe I did it wrong before or something), so I am confident that they are brought to the front."  But have you tried doing that in the CODE itself after setting the `.Text` property? `Side2HPText2.BringToFront();`

Comment: Remember that a PictureBox is not a ContainerControl, so you cannot *parent* any Control to it in the Form Designer, you have to do it in code. This means you have to relocate the label **after** you have set the new Parent, then you'll see it. If you don't force its Parent in code, you can be shown **under** the PictureBox or, whe shown above it, it may carry the backcolor of its current Parent, probably the Form. As already mentioned, you're better off drawing that text, or building a Custom/User Control or use, e.g., a [custom ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053257/7444103).

Comment: @ericfolmer Try commenting out the line `this.Side2HPText2.Anchor = ...;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also have brought the Labels to the front several times now(thinking
> that maybe I did it wrong before or something), so I am confident that
> they are brought to the front.

But have you tried doing that in the CODE itself after setting the `.Text` property?

```
...
Side2HPText2.Text = side2HPbox2DisplayNum + " %";
Side2HPText2.BringToFront();
```

> @Idle_Mind that worked, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about making my own answer post to resolve the thread from your comment, but I wasn't sure if I was supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms controls cannot overlap. There is a special-case for "transparent" control backgrounds, but that's just an trick (a "transparent" background control requests its parent form repaint its background first, then the control paints itself).

This is because WinForms controls are their own hWnd surfaces, and WinForms does not support transparent control backgrounds or alpha-blending.

Comment: I have already lain a label on top of a PictureBox before, and it's worked fine. You can even see it working in one of the images I have already displayed in my question: it works fine for one of the labels that is overlapping a PictureBox, just not the rest.

Comment: @EricFolmer `PictureBox` uses the background-painting trick as well, btw. But you can't overlap two `PictureBox` controls over each other. I'll admit that I haven't looked at your code too closely, but I suspect you may be running into problems with the painting-**order** which I believe is defined by the order that the controls are added to the `Controls` collection (rather than any Z-ordering). Please post your VS-generated `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: sorry, my ```InitializeComponent``` method doesn't fit within the character limit, even if I were to delete everything else. Here's a Pastebin of it(hopefully not against the rules): https://pastebin.com/WRRJ5n4d